# Product Images fail to load after Version upgrade magento 2.2.9

Tags: magento2, error, image, magento-upgrade

I tried to upgrade version 2.2.1 to 2.2.9 and for some reason images inside the product catalog on the frontend load forever.
I did research and tried all the below solutions

https://www.ctidigital.com/blog/fixing-image-resize-issues-after-upgrading-to-magento-2.1.6

https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016052033-Pictures-Images-not-showing-in-category-page-after-updating-from-M2-2-x-to-Magento-2-3

Cleared product cache, magento cache - nothing works.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: refer this link if that's relevant to you 

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137072/product-image-does-not-load-on-product-page**

**https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Images-not-loading-on-product-View-page-Magento-2-2-5/td-p/99439**

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175224/regenerate-catalog-cache-images-issues**

Answer (score 1):

I also had a same problem.  fixed my problem by running these commands.

1.Catalog Reindex - $sudo php bin/magento index:reindex

2. Re-generate the image catalog by using the command below via CLI: 
   $sudo php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
3. Clear the cache.